# How do I ensure that what I post on Facebook stays private?

Tags: facebook, privacy

On Facebook, how should I adjust my privacy settings so that my posts stay private?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Honestly, if you are really concerned with the privacy of your account it may be better to not post anything you would not want to be public.

Comment: Seconded. Always post information on the internet with the expectation that it will be propagated outside of your control. This way, you'll never be surprised when/if it does. :)

Comment: 100% agree.  The sad part is I now must preface picture opportunities with friends as "please don't post this on Facebook, etc.."

Comment: Imagine Justin was asking the same thing in the real world. There's a bulletin board, in a physically secured office, that only he and his colleagues can see. What they don't realize is that over the New Year's holiday the bulletin board is moved to the lobby. Nobody knew about this, nobody even thought to ask. They *thought* they were doing the right thing keeping their little world private. Of course you can say, "If you're really concerned about privacy then you shouldn't post anything on that private bulletin board", but that's not really the question.

Comment: This is not a good answer to the question.  For example: I might post something on Facebook about going away on vacation.  I'm not concerned about my Facebook friends knowing this.  There'd be no reason for them to trumpet it around.  But it would be crazy to post it to the entire world, as my house would probably get burglarized while I was gone.  Most information on Facebook isn't interesting enough that people will spread it to the entire world.  The question is how *I* can keep from spreading it to the entire world when I post.

Answer (score 18):

1. Click `Account`
2. Click `Privacy Settings`
3. Either:

   - Simple:

     1. Click `Friends Only`
   - Advanced:

     1. Click `Custom`
     2. Click `Customize Settings`
     3. Click `Posts by me`
     4. Select `Friends Only`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [ReclaimPrivacy](http://www.reclaimprivacy.org/facebook), they have a very easy to use javascript bookmark which allows you to see where your privacy might leak.

Comment: I used that, but ran it 4 times and got 4 different answers, so I frankly don't trust it very much.